# How to change a jQuery method depending on value of a boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the jQuery method

```
parent()
```

to

```
children()
```

depending on the width of the user's screen.

Here's what I have (relevant code snippet):

```
var me         = $(this);
var generation = $(window).width() > 767 ? 'parent' : 'children';
if( !me.is(e.target) && !me.is($(e.target)[generation]() ) {
    me.removeClass(activeClass);
}
```

This is doing nothing no matter the screen size and also isnt throwing an error...

If I log the variable
    generation 
to the console on the event the correct string returns according to the screen size check so I must be screwing up the way the method is being written in.

Anyone have insight here?

Comment: Where does this code exist? If it's in an event handler, `this` is the same as `e.target`, so `!me.is(e.target)` will never be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that you are missing a `)`

[1] Try:

```
var me         = $(this);
var generation = $(window).width() > 767 ? 'parent' : 'children';
if (!me.is(e.target) && !me.is(($(e.target)[generation])())) {
    me.removeClass(activeClass);
}
```

[2] Or why not do:

```
var me         = $(this);
var generation = $(window).width() > 767;
if (!me.is(e.target) && ((generation == true && !me.is($(e.target).parent())) || (generation == false && !me.is($(e.target).children())))) {
    me.removeClass(activeClass);
}
```

[3] Or this:

```
var me = $(this);
if ($(window).width() > 767 && !me.is(e.target) && !me.is($(e.target).parent())) {
    me.removeClass(activeClass);
} else if (!me.is(e.target) && !me.is($(e.target).children())) {
    me.removeClass(activeClass);
}
```

[4] Or this:

```
var me    = $(this);
var check = $(window).width() > 767 ? $(e.target).parent() : $(e.target).children();
if (!me.is(e.target) && !me.is(check)) {
    me.removeClass(activeClass);
}
```

Comment: Hey your second snippet seems to work so I'll accept in in a second, though I wa able to solve this on my own with: var generation = $(window).width() > 767 ? $(e.target).parent() : $(e.target).children();

Comment: Great! I added my fourth before I knew you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
$(window).width() > 767 ? parent() : children();
```

Comment: tried that earlier - returns undefined but revisiting that did just give me an idea...

Comment: it will return whatever the functions parent() / children() are returning, modify them according to what you need?

Comment: `parent` and `children` aren't global functions, they're jQuery methods.

Comment: @saranshkataria - with all due respect I dont think this will work for reason Barmar states